# Sous-Vide cook out juices

Tags: sous-vide, glaze

I’ve been trying out various styles of thickening the sauce inside the bag while cooking. My focus is creating a marinade style/glaze while cooking my meat, so when it comes out, I can just flame grill. 
My sauce keeps splitting (oil separation) - Is there anyone who has been successful in creating a glaze with the end product?

Answer (score 4):

The issue with accomplishing what you want to in the bag is the low temperature typically used in sous vide cooking.  These low temperatures prevent the proteins from coagulating.  This can only happen once you dump the juices into a pan to finish a sauce at higher temperatures. Then, you will probably notice that you get globs of coagulated proteins, which are less than appetizing.  So, you will want to pour the juices into a pot, bring to a simmer, and skim the proteins (or strain them out).  Now you can use the broth as a stock to create a sauce.  Remember though, you will have to build flavor, as these juices are generally not that flavorful.  In your case, you will need to bring to a boil, skim or strain, then reduce significantly to create a glaze.

Comment: IMO, At that point, you'd be better off ditching sous-vide altogether and just grill the meat directly.

Comment: @Jeffrey, not necessarily, plenty of folks sous vide then grill to finish.  I'm not a big user of the bag juice myself, but in that case the OP would not have any drippings for a glaze.

Comment: I generally agree with moscafj. Use those juices to make a sauce afterwards. You don't have to be traditional if you don't want to, use xanthan or something if you feel like it.